# function works fine in Chrome but does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, function

Friends my function works fine in Chrome but does not work in Firefox and gives error: `Uncaught TypeError: Property 'handleEvent' is not callable`.

my function : `function test(){ var a12= parseInt(document.querySelector("#number").value);var a13 = a12.toLocaleString();   SendOrderApi.setOrderCount(a13);}`

What is the cause of this error? And how do I fix this?

```js
function test(){ 
  var a2= parseInt(document.querySelector("#number").value);
  var a3 = a2.toLocaleString(); 
  document.getElementById("s01").innerText=a3;
}
```

```html
<input id="number" type="number" onmousewheel="test()">
<br>
<span id="s01">12</span>
```

Comment: Firefox doesn't support `onmousewheel`: https://caniuse.com/?search=onmousewheel . There's a note that says: This feature is deprecated/obsolete and should not be used.

Comment: thank you for your answer@ÁlvaroGonzález

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mousewheel` [isn't a standard handler](https://caniuse.com/?search=onmousewheel). The [standard is `wheel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/wheel_event):

```js
function test(){ 
  var a2= parseInt(document.querySelector("#number").value);
  var a3 = a2.toLocaleString(); 
  document.getElementById("s01").innerText=a3;
}
```

```html
<input id="number" type="number" onwheel="test()">
<br>
<span id="s01">12</span>
```

Comment: Another question is why the amount being replaced is not equal to the input value?

Comment: Probably the `wheel` event triggers before the input gets changed. You may want to just use `change`.